# How to specify title of the pin when using Pinterest api

Tags: php, rest, api, pinterest

I am using the Pinterest api, https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/, with PHP to create the pin to my board, and it is working properly except one thing.

All the pin I created with api do not have title. I checked the api multiple times and I didn't find any parameter for title.

Does anyone here know how I can create a pin with title using Pinterest's api?

This is a pint with title:

[image: img]

This is pint I created with api, it doesn't have title:

[image: img]

[An example of one pin that has title and one without, sorry for the link, I don't have enough reputation to embed image yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlG5x.png)

Below is the code that I use to make the API calls with PHP:

```
    $ch=curl_init();                                              
    $post= array(
        "access_token" => 'my token',
        "board"  => $board,
        "link"  => $link,
        "note"  => $note,
        "image_url" => $image
    );
    $host = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
```

Comment: Can you share an API request as you are currently making them?

Comment: @zbee I don't have access to the code now, once I get home, I will post it

Comment: still waiting for any answer. i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the field you are looking for is `note` in the pin object.

This field controls the description that resides under the pin, which is what I think you are pointing out.

Comment: I do have the note parameter. But based on my observation, only title is shown under the pin in the feed (list), description is only shown when the user clicks on the pin, the close up view.

Comment: I have added the code for the API request,  I am using curl to make the api call with php.